# Binding to BitmapImage retrieved from Active Directory not working

Tags: c#, wpf, active-directory, bitmapimage

I have a piece of code that retrieves a user's image from Active Directory and then updates a bound `BitmapImage` property with it.

The XAML looks like:

```
            <Image Width="30"
                   Height="30"
                   Margin="10"
                   DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                   Source="{Binding UserImage}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

The property is defined as:

```
        public BitmapImage UserImage
        {
            get
            {
                return _userImage;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_userImage != value)
                {
                    _userImage = value;
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("UserImage"));
                }
            }
        }
```

Finally, the code that updates the property is:

```
            PrincipalContext principleContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, HAL_Globals.domain);
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principleContext,    IdentityType.SamAccountName, HAL_Globals.domain + "\\" + _usernameSearchText);
            DirectoryEntry userEntry = (user.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry);

            if (userEntry != null)
            {
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(userEntry.Properties["thumbnailPhoto"].Value as byte[]))
                {
                    BitmapImage userImage = new BitmapImage();
                    userImage.BeginInit();
                    userImage.StreamSource = stream;
                    userImage.EndInit();

                    UserImage = userImage;
                }
            }
```

The problem is the image in the view is not being updated with anything. I have debugged the image being created and it looks *ok*, however the debugging tool doesn't support previewing that type so it's hard to verify. I have tried binding to an 64 bit encoded image string instead but had no luck. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `BitmapCacheOptions.OnLoad` when you want to close the stream directly after initializing the BitmapImage:

```
var userImage = new BitmapImage();

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(...))
{
    userImage.BeginInit();
    userImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    userImage.StreamSource = stream;
    userImage.EndInit();
}

UserImage = userImage;
```

See the Remarks section in [BitmapImage.CacheOption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.cacheoption.aspx):

> Set the CacheOption to BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad if you wish to close a
>   stream used to create the BitmapImage. ...